# Twitter JSON URL for user timeline

Tags: ios, twitter, hashtag

I have a simple question, in my iOS app I have the twitter search api. I am looking to implement instead a search for hastags and user timelines. For hastags I have the url: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23HASHTAGHERE But I was unable to find the JSON url for a user's timeline. If someone can point me to this that would be great. Thank You

CURRENT FOR HASTAG:

> ```
> NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=&ands=%@&phrase=&rpp=50",searchTerm];
>   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];       //Setup and start async download
> ```
>
> NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]
>   initWithURL:url];     NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection
>   alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL for a user's timeline: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json

Source: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Note that this is for iOS 5+ since it uses `TWRequest`

```
    NSURL *getTimeline = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"];

    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               <twitter screen name goes here>, @"screen_name",
                                nil];

    TWRequest *twitterRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:getTimeline
                                                    parameters:parameters
                                                 requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

//Set a twitter account (Gotten from iOS 5+)
    [twitterRequest setAccount:self.twitterAccount];

    [twitterRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {             
             JSONDecoder *decoder = [[JSONDecoder alloc] initWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionNone];
             NSArray *twitterTimeline = [decoder objectWithData:responseData];

         }
         else
         {
             //Deal with error
         }


     }];
```

If you just want a JSON timeline without any authentication, etc, then you can use:
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=(screen-name-here)

Comment: can u give an example. thank you. https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/@jayleno.json

Comment: Edited with sample code - check it out and let me know if you need any further help/clarification. Cheers!

Comment: I am not looking for the users timeline but I want the user to be able to type in anyones name and then I can pull up the timeline

Comment: Not sure what the issue is - code above is for any user. So just put the name that you want into the `screen_name` parameter of the `parameters` dictionary. As long as you have access, you'll get the timeline.

Comment: Thank you for doing this but if u see above how I am doing this I just use the url. So i get the getTimeline part but do I need the TWRequest part can I just get a url and use JSON like I am currently if u see my update above. Essentially is there just a url i can make with the users screen name and not deal with the parameters? Thank You.

Comment: No problem.  However note that without authentication, if you're not an 'approved follower' of some people, it will fail - as per the docs:  The other users timeline will only be visible if they are not protected, or if the authenticating user's follow request was accepted by the protected user.

Comment: do i have to use the unauth way for hashtags and auth for usertimlines or I can do both with auth.

Comment: I was using :  NSDictionary *tweets = [results objectForKey:@"results"]; but now I get an error when I use the url for usertimlines. Any idea why?

Comment: Because that will access a dictionary with the key 'results' - the timeline API returns an array so it would be `NSArray *tweets = results` - you can look at the data in a browser and you'll see that there's no 'results' key covering the data

Comment: Sorry for all the questions. Is there a url that also includes the mentions in the timeline?

Comment: Check out this URL: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline - you want the include_entities parameter: When set to either true, t or 1, each tweet will include a node called "entities,". This node offers a variety of metadata about the tweet in a discreet structure, including: user_mentions, urls, and hashtags